# save as dialog box for exporting file to excel C#

Tags: c#, database, excel

I am exporting multiple datatable as different worksheets to a single excel file and it is working fine. However, the excel file is saved to the path specified. I want a save as dialog from where the user can select the path to save the file. I have tried the following code on button click:

```
protected void excelexport(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sql = null;
        string data = null;
        string path = "C:\\inetpub/wwwroot/MahindraEarth/exportexcel/exportexcel";

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        System.Data.DataTable dts = new System.Data.DataTable(); ;
        System.Data.DataTable dss = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Enquiry gs = new Enquiry();
        ResultClass objres = gs.fn_GetEnquiryList();
        if (objres.bStatus)
        {
            eslist<Enquiry> OBJLIST = objres.objData as eslist<Enquiry>;
            if (OBJLIST.Count > 0)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)OBJLIST;
            }
        }
        Operator op = new Operator();
        ResultClass objrest = op.fn_GetOperatorList();
        if (objrest.bStatus)
        {
            eslist<Operator> OBJLISTS = objrest.objData as eslist<Operator>;
            if (OBJLISTS.Count > 0)
            {
                dts = (DataTable)OBJLISTS;
            }
        }
        Contact co = new Contact();
        ResultClass objress = co.fn_GetContactList();
        if (objress.bStatus)
        {
            eslist<Contact> OBJLISS = objress.objData as eslist<Contact>;
            if (OBJLISS.Count > 0)
            {
                dss = (DataTable)OBJLISS;
            }
        }

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dts);
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dss);
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

        String[] Worksheets = new String[dataSet.Tables.Count];
        Excel.Worksheet[] xlWorkSheet = new Excel.Worksheet[dataSet.Tables.Count];
        for (int k = 0; k < dataSet.Tables.Count; k++)
        {
            DataTable dst = dataSet.Tables[k];
            xlWorkSheet[k] = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(k + 1);

            for (i = 0; i <= dst.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dst.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet[k].Cells[1, j + 1] = dataSet.Tables[k].Columns[j].ColumnName;
                    data = dst.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet[k].Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
                    xlWorkSheet[k].Name = dataSet.Tables[k].TableName;
                }
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
        for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++)
        {
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet[p]);
        }
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
        exportsuccess.Style.Add("display", "");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

How to get the save as dialog box in order to save the multiple datatables in multiple worksheet and not as a single sheet.

Thanks,

Comment: Off topic, you should never have empty `catch` statements.

Comment: Do you want that the user could save the file on the server, by specifying the server path? It sounds like a very high security issue. Btw, is this WinForms or Web?

Comment: no i want the user to download the file using the save dialog box

Answer (score 0):

give this a try.  This should give you the Save As dialog box.  Some of the code should look similar to yours, which should give you an idea as to where this code excerpt should be attached.

```
    #region Save & Quit
    //Save and quit, use SaveCopyAs since SaveAs does not always work
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
    string uniqueFileName = id.ToString() + ".xls";
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/" + uniqueFileName);
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false; //Supress overwrite request
    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    //Release objects
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);

    //Give the user the option to save the copy of the file anywhere they desire
    String FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/" + uniqueFileName);
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyClaimsReport-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xls;");
    response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
    response.Flush();
    response.Close();

    //Delete the temporary file
    DeleteFile(fileName);
    #endregion

private void DeleteFile(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Could not delete the file, wait and try again
            try
            {
                System.GC.Collect();
                System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                File.Delete(fileName);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Could not delete the file still
            }
        }
    }
}
```